# How to parse a json of the below format?

Tags: php, json, ajax

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Bangalore"},{"id":"3","name":"Mysore"}]
```

I tried using the below code but its not giving me any output

```
var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(response); // now obj is a json object
alet(obj.id);
$("#state").html("<option value='"+ obj.id +"'>'"+ obj.name +"'</option>");
$("#state").next().next().html("<li rel='"+ obj.id +"'>"+ obj.name +"</li>");
```

Comment: above encoded Json is getting as response here

Comment: obj.id will not exists on `alert(obj.id)`. You have to use foreach loop over this parsed object.

Comment: So `alert(obj[0].id)` will do for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is a JSON array containing two objects. Therefore, you need to read it as an array first, before accessing the `id`:

```
alert(obj[0].id);
```

To loop all, you will write something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    console.log("ID: " + obj[i].id);
};
```

Comment: so if i write a for loop to get all object. How ill i get no of objects ??

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array

```
  var response=jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    var li='';

 for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
       li=li+ "<option value='"+ response[i].id +"'>'"+ response[i].name +"'</option>";
    }

    $("#state").html(li);
```